# How can I do the reverse of zip/mesh from List::MoreUtils?

Tags: perl

I have two arrays:

```
@foo = (1, 2, 3, 4);
@bar = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

If I zip them with `mesh`/`zip` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#mesh-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3), I get this:

```
@zipped = (1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 4, 'D');
```

How can I do this operation backwards, i.e. starting from `@zipped` how can I get `@foo` and `@bar`?

Answer (score 8):

List::Util::pairs.

```
use List::Util 'pairs';
my @zipped = ('1', 'A', '2', 'B', '3', 'C');
my ($foo, $bar) = pairs @zipped;
```

`$foo` and `$bar` will be references to arrays containing `('1'..'3')` and `('A'..'C')`, respectively.

Or if there are more than two arrays, use List::MoreUtils::part:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'part';
my @zipped = ('1', 'A', 'a', '2', 'B', 'b', '3', 'C', 'c');
my $number_of_arrays = 3;

my $i = 0;
my @arrayrefs = part { $i++ % $number_of_arrays } @zipped;
```

Comment: Actualy, it's not working for me... it doesn't recognize the 'pairs' as part of the Util

Comment: it was added in version 1.28 (August 2013); you probably have an older version.  After many years of essentially no feature changes, new stuff started getting added to List::Util a couple of years ago.